# Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0 generation - adding a new content-type hides previous schema information

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am using Java annotations to build our swagger documentation.  In one case, we want to provide output in either JSON or csv depending on the "Accepts" header.  I created the rest interface like this:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v2/swaggerTest")
@Api
public class SwaggerDocResource {

    private static class ItemDto {
        String name;
        Integer age;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the requested items in json")
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ItemDto> getItems() {
        return null;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the requested items in csv")
    @GetMapping(produces = "text/csv")
    public ResponseEntity<String> exportItems() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If I comment out the csv method, the generated Swagger doc generates a schema for my DTO class and references it:

```
...
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ItemDto"
                }
            }
        }
    },
...
```

However, if I do include the csv method, the schema for my DTO class is no longer generated and both types of response are given the same schema:

```
...
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "text/csv": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Is it possible to assign a different schema to these different content types?  I have been unable to figure out how.